# Сразу два вопроса.Как к каждому элементу(int) set прибавить другое значение(тоже int)? И как добавить наименьший элемент в set в его конец?

Tags: c++, stl, set

То есть у меня есть set ,там например 5 целочисленных значений
Мне нужно к каждому элементу прибавить еще число,то есть увеличить его на x
И второй вопрос:Допустим в set 5 элементов от 1 до 5
Как мне добавить 1 в конец ,если он автоматически сортирует коллекцию?
Помогите пожалуйста,не могу разобраться

Comment: Это явно проблема XY. Чего вы пытаетесь добиться этими действиями, особенно добавлением в конец упорядоченного контейнера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решительно невозможно менять элементы во множестве. Потому они и объявлены как `const`.

Они располагаются упорядоченно, и тут врываетесь вы и хотите превратить, скажем,

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

в

```
1 8 3 12 5
```

Все, элементы находятся в неупорядоченном состоянии... Вы можете возразить, что не собираетесь нарушать упорядоченность - но откуда об этом знать компилятору?

Так что разрешенный способ один - получить элемент, изменить, добавить во множество, старый удалить...

Тот же ответ и на второй вопрос - никак. Потому что порядок элементов во множестве устанавливается самим множеством. Используйте в таком случае что-то другое - `vector`, например.

P.S. для кулхацкеров...
Конечно, можно пойти на нарушения типа

```
set<int> s = { 5,4,3,2,1};
for(int i: s) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
for(const int& i: s) if (i%2 == 0) ((int&)i)+=5;
for(int i: s) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
```

и они могут даже [сработать](https://ideone.com/fG4U4u)... Но это очень нездоровое занятие - нарушать инвариант класса. Как себя после этого поведет класс - проблематично, например, в этом же примере вы видите, что получается множество с двумя одинаковыми элементами, чего быть не должно...

Comment: Мне казалось, я ответил на оба вопроса. Но индексу обращаться ко множеству вы не можете, не предусмотрено. Обходить можете циклом по диапазону, как показали, можете через итератор (`for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)...`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ устроил - закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ ("птичка" слева от ответа).

Comment: *Решительно невозможно менять элементы во множестве.* - только в бестолковых контейнерах из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @user7860670 Как я понимаю, следующий наезд будет на сам язык :) Когда будете пользоваться толковыми контейнерами, поинтересуйтесь эффективностью операции изменения значения в ассоциативном контейнере.

Comment: Откуда такой скептицизм? Все весьма эффективно. Если каждый элемент увеличить на x, то ведь даже переупорядочивать ничего не нужно будет.

Comment: @user7860670 Но нужно будет проверить, не нарушилось ли упорядочение - O(n). Проще удалить-вставить - O(log N). Что, вероятно, и будет делать за сценой "толковый" контейнер...

Comment: Если в контейнере числа, упорядоченные по убыванию или по возрастанию, то не нужно. Ведь итоговый порядок не изменится.

Comment: @user7860670 Это знаете вы. Но откуда это знать компилятору?...

Comment: А того, что знаю я, вполне достаточно. Зачем об этом знать компилятору? Вся процедура сводится к обходу контейнера с модификацией каждого элемента. При этом нет никакой необходимости как-то уведомлять контейнер об этих изменениях, главное не пытаться что-то еще с ним делать, пока тот находится в неупорядоченном состоянии.

Comment: @user7860670 Второй... Один - который все время на все мои ответы и комментарии талдычил - программа слетает на строчке `free(array)`, значит, ошибка в ней - уже был :) Вы в этом моем списке людей, с которыми лучше не спорить, второй...

Comment: Может вы просто никогда не использовали ассоциативные контейнеры, допускающие модификацию элементов? Попробуйте boost. Гетерогенный поиск, пересадку нод, и прочее из него уже добавили в стандартные контейнеры, может и возможность модифицировать элементы и полноценные интрузивные интерфейсы тоже когда-нибудь завезут.